# Hibernate OnetoMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement OnetoMany relationship for two tables student and certificates. I have two classes, Student and Certificates which have OnetoMany relationship from Student class to Certificates class.

Student Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable{

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="student") 
    private List<Certificats> listCertificats;
    // Getters and Setters
```

Certificats class:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "certificates")
   public class Certificates implements Serializable{

        @Id  
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="student_id")
        private Student student;    
        // Getters and Setters
```

My DAO class has a method to fetch data from the database:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Students> listStudents() {

        List<Students> studentList;

        studentList= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Student").list();

        return studentList;
    }
```

Now when I run this method, the value for the listCertificats in the Student class which is a List is always null. However, I get value for id field in the Student class. What am I doing wrong here? I checked some tutorials for Hibernate OnetoMany relationship and they described the same way I implemented. Any would be much appreciated.

Comment: I assume you create test data. Have you ensured that you establish the relation between both entities before save. (student.getListCertificates().add(certificate);certificate.setStudent(student)) otherwise hibernate can behave unexpected depending on the internal session state.

Comment: I am relatively new. Can you explain in details?

Comment: You need to insert data into the db to read something and I mean that code. You use a bidirectional mapping. That can cause failures when not used properly

Comment: I have data in the database. I just want to read the data.

Comment: Then show us the data format; How you access your data or anything other usefull.

Comment: Like @mh-dev said, first check that the links exits (check the correct value of field student_id). Casue list of certificate is set lazy-initialization when you get students Hibernate loads only the student object and replaces list of certificates by q proxy. If you access the proxy, Hibernate uses the current session to initialize the proxy and load the entries from the database.

Comment: ....but in your scenario could not be the case, try using the method Hibernate.initialize(objStuden.listCertificate) or use query like "from student s fetch s.liatCertificate" for the special case that needs to load the list along with the student object.

Answer (score 0):

FetchType.lazy implies that you will not be seeing data of your child entities until you access specific properties of them.

Please specify when are you seeing null? Are you seeing null even when you access them?

Comment: I did not have cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY first time. I added those to try in different way, and every time I see null. To specify, I see null when I try to access a specific field. I know there is a problem in my code or setting. I am just trying to understand where that is. My data in the database has a simple one to many relationship. It would also be helpful to know if need a different approach to fetch data from those tables. I thought if I use onetomany relationship, it will fetch data from both tables automatically according to the relationship between the table.